# I want to get the id for div which is display block from last to first div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Example:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="1" style="display:block"></div>
    <div id="23" style="display:block"></div>
    <div id="42" style="display:block"></div>
    <div id="32" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

According to this example i want to get the id of div id=42 which is at the second last position. i want to find div which is display block and find from last.

Comment: you need to show some code i guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case u can use:

```
var last_id = $('div:visible').last().attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find it by this way

```
$("#parent div[style*='display:block']'").last().attr("id")
```

See jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UhzRU/4/

If you want to find all visible div's(not only display:block) it will be better to use this

```
$("#parent div:visible").last().attr("id")
```

Comment: add a space between the `:` and `block` and you get `undefined`. it can be faulty that way.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to *get the id for div which is **display block** from last to first* div?

[here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fskreuz/bwZu5/2/)

```
$(function(){

    var ids = [];

    $('#parent > *').filter(function(){
        return this.style.display === 'block'; 
    }).each(function(){
        ids.unshift(this.id);
    });

    console.log(ids)
});​
```

Comment: Don't you think it's very long solution?

Comment: @ChuckNorris nope. the only things important here is the filter, the get and reverse.

Comment: Yes, there are too more actions when this can be done with more simple way :)

Comment: well, i missed something, and updated it. now it's according to what the OP wants

Comment: @ChuckNorris Your solution is shorter, but does something completely different.  Your solution simply finds the id of the last div, while Joseph's answer gets a list of divs in reverse order.  The OP is not very clear on what he wants exactly, but I interpreted his question just like Joseph.

Comment: @Steve i missed the part where he needed the ***IDs of the divs*** (and not the divs themselves) in reverse. i updated it.

Comment: @Joseph I actually interpreted it the same way you did in your first solution... but you might be correct with what you have now.  It's tricky because the OP's question is not very clear.

Comment: @Steve I'm pretty sure that OP wants to find only id of last display:block div, not the list of divs. He writes a description too " i want to get the id of div id=42 which is at the second last position".

Comment: @ChuckNorris so what's there to do "last-to-first" if you only get one? the title of the OP's post says it all.

Comment: @Joseph, it's OP's english :) I think he means to get first id counting from end.

Comment: @ChuckNorris Maybe... we don't know for sure, because the OP's question is unclear. Looking at the headline, I interpreted "from last to first div" as looking for a list.  Either way, all I am saying is that you were unjustly criticizing Joseph for an answer that is too long, when in fact it is perfect for what it is doing.

Comment: @Steve, I wrote about previous answer of Joseph, after that he edited his answer. So, now it's good.Let's wait OP to see what he really wants :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for your test HTML

```
x = $('#parent div').filter(function() {if ($(this).css('display') == 'block') return $('this')});
x = x[x.length - 1];
```

`x` is now the last div with `display: block;`

Answer (score 0):

Use nth-last-child function: Here is a link

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-misc-plugins/#nth-last-child

```
(function($){
  '$:nomunge'; // Used by YUI compressor.

  $.fn.queueFn = function( fn ) {
    var i,
      that,
      args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );

    if ( typeof fn === 'boolean' ) {
      if ( fn ) {
        that = this;
        i = this.length;
      }
      fn = args.shift();
    }

    fn = $.isFunction( fn ) ? fn : $.fn[ fn ];

    return this.queue(function(){
      !--i && fn.apply( that || this, args );
      $.dequeue( this );
    });
  };

})(jQuery);

var elems = $('#parent div:nth-last-child(2)');
alert(elems.attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works

```
var reqId = ""
var child = $("#parent").children().last();
while($(child).css("display")!="block" && $(child).length!=0){
    child = $(child).prev();
}
if($(child).length!=0){
   reqId = $(child).attr("id");
}
```